# What's the purpose of the Metadata section in a CloudFormation Template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

AWS describes the overall CloudFormation Template anatomy in [this doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-anatomy.html).
It states that the **Metadata** section is a JSON object that provides additional information about the template.
In [this doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/metadata-section-structure.html), we can see that the only provided examples of using the Metadata section are:

- `AWS::CloudFormation::Init`: but [it seems](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html) that **the only place** where it can be used is in the **Resource Metadata** section and *not in the template Metadata* section. Isn't it?
- `AWS::CloudFormation::Interface`
- `AWS::CloudFormation::Designer`

The question is can we really have **an arbitrary JSON** in the Template Metadata section? And if so, what can be its purpose?

Note: The question is not about the Resource Metadata but the Template Metadata section.

Comment: Seems like this question hasn't really been answered? AFAICT, `WS::CloudFormation::Init` accepts meta data only on an `AWS::EC2::Instance` and `AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration` type?

Comment: To the question 'What's the purpose of the Metadata section in a CloudFormation Template?', the answer is 'Arbitrary additional information to be used by third party tools (your tools, the CloudFormation designer, even other AWS resources, etc.).' The question is general, and cited examples only try to gather existing usage across AWS.

Comment: Yes fair enough. I guess I'll ask a new question because I also find the documentation is unclear about where cfn-init's metadata is allowed to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CloudFormation designer UI uses `AWS::CloudFormation::Designer` in this area to store additional presentation data.

Other third party tools that generate and modify templates could use template metadata to store additional information and/or state.

Comment: Using the CloudFormation Designer, it seems to store its additional data in the `AWS::CloudFormation::Designer` section of the Metadata section. By the way, If I understand, the Metadata section is not used in any purpose by CloudFormation itself but can be used by third party tools to store additional information? If you agree please edit your answer and I will accept it.